# Descartes' theorem and Circle Packing

Tags: geometry, circle-packing

There's something I am missing comparing Descartes' theorem for three isometric circles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) and this wiki post on circle packing of 3 circles [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html).

From my calculation:

$$
r_{ext} = \frac{r_{int}}{{(3\pm2\sqrt3)}}, \tag{1}
$$

where *r<sub>ext</sub>* is the external radius and  *r<sub>int</sub>* the internal radius. In the second article it seems:

$$
r_{ext} = r_{int}(1+2\frac{\sqrt3}{3}). \tag{2}
$$

(Probably is crappy mathematics of my own.)

For the sake of completness. The generic formula I derived from Descartes' theorem is (for different radii):

$$
r_{ext} = \frac{r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}}{(r_{1}r_{2}+r_{2}r_{3}+r_{1}r_{3} \pm 2{\sqrt{r_{1}r_{2}r_{3}(r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3})}{}})}. \tag{3}
$$

what am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear what you denote by $r_{ext}$ and $r_{int}$. Please define/describe the problem precisely, including notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. I misunderstood the second article:

$$
1+2\frac{\sqrt{(3)}}{3}
$$

is the coefficient in a linear expression. Both the solutions are the same, you can derive (2) from (1) using square difference formula.

Answer (score 1):

The $k$s in the Wiki article are the curvatures (the inverses of the radii). If you correct for that, the two numbers will agree.

Comment: I've already done that. I could show you the complete formula for radii instead curvatures. My calculations seems right I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: Mathematica disagrees...

Comment: I imagine that, but I uninstalled mathematica a long time ago, i'm more interested in what my mistake was.